# Кодировка окна ошибок в QtCreator(3.4)

Tags: qtcreator

[image]
Здравствуйте. Вот такого вида текст ошибок в редакторе, как пофиксить?

Comment: Установи английскую студию или переименую файл чтобы сообщения были на английском %VSINSTALLDIR%\VC\bin\1049\clui.dll

Comment: А вообще на багтрекере уже много лет висит баг но его никто не собирается исправлять https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-316

Comment: @zenden2k, пожалуйста. оформите изложенное в виде ответа.

Answer (score 2):

Мой ответ не лечит русские буквы.

Установи английскую студию чтобы сообщения были на английском  или переименуй файл`%VSINSTALLDIR%\VC\bin\1049\clui.dll`

А вообще на багтрекере уже много лет [висит баг](http://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-316) но его никто не собирается исправлять.